# Why does the add function interrupt my while loop?

Tags: python, set

I worked on a function all_dice(), which should take a choice value, of how many dice a user wants to throw and then throws the according number of dice.
I want to store each roll_() variable in an empty set thisset=set() to be able to get my final score just by returning and printing all_dice(). But what I get is only one value. The set-idea seems to intercept the while loop. F.e when I set choice == 5, thisset only contains {4}. If it d work as intended, the function should start by choice=5, get a roll_() number, store it in thisset{}, then counting down by choice=choice-1, go to choice==4, and so on. So with choice=5, id expect 5 values inside thisset{}.

without the thisset.add() function, the all_dice() function works as intended - counting down the choices and producing corresponding values.

Can someone tell me why the while loop would be intercepted/ what the problem is?

This is my first program, so please be gentle with me
-thx for your help!

```
#function to role many dice 
import random
choice =5
print("choice is:",choice)
def all_dice(choice):
    while choice>=1:
        thisset=set()
        if choice==1:
            roll_1=random.randint(1,6)
            thisset.add(roll_1)
            choice=choice-1
        if choice==2:
            roll_2=random.randint(1,6)
            thisset.add(roll_2)
            choice=choice-1
        if choice==3:
            roll_3=random.randint(1,6)
            thisset.add(roll_3)
            choice=choice-1
        if choice==4:
            roll_4=random.randint(1,6)
            thisset.add(roll_4)
            choice=choice-1
        if choice==5:
            roll_5=random.randint(1,6)
            thisset.add(roll_5)
            choice=choice-1
    return thisset
print(all_dice(choice))
```

Comment: There's no reason for all the `if` statements, since you do the same thing in each of them.

Comment: Nothing to do with set addition, it's the fact that you initialize a new empty `set()` in each run of the loop, so it will only ever contain one number

Comment: thank you for helping - but that was my only idea of how to store 5 different values for 5 different dice. And does that correspond with/ would solve the problem of all_dice storing the values of each throw_ in an empty set ?

Comment: @xobqox Couldn't you use a list?

Answer (score 1):

You're clearing the set each time through the loop, so you lose the previous items. You need to initialize it just once *before* the loop. (For some reason this type of error is very common among beginners.)

And you don't need all those different variables or `if` statements, since they all do the same thing.

```
def all_dice(choice):
    thisset = set()
    for _ in range(choice):
        thisset.add(random.randint(1, 6))
    return thisset
```

I'm not sure why you would use a set for rolling multiple dice. A set can't have duplicates, so if you roll the same number multiple times, the set will only contain one of them. If you want to roll 5 dice you would normally use a list to hold all the rolls. And if you only care about the sum, you don't need to save all the different rolls at all, just add them to a total variable.

Comment: I just tried your solution - thank you very much for your help! It now sends me an value of one dice each time. I will try to store these values in a list now!

Comment: AFAIK a set will only allow you to have one of each value... so your set with 6 possible values cannot have a length > 6

Comment: @TenaciousB I tried to explain that in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most pythonic way I can think of to do it. I would NOT recommend using a `set()` unless you never want duplicates in your data:

```
import random

def roll_dice(rolls=1):
    return [random.randint(1, 6) for roll in range(rolls)]

roll_dice(5)
```

Or another way to do it:

```
import random

roll_dice = lambda rolls: [random.randint(1, 6) for roll in range(rolls)]

roll_dice(5)
```

Output:

```
[2, 1, 1, 5, 1]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#function to role many dice 
import random
choice =5
print("choice is:",choice)
def all_dice(choice):
    thisset = [] 
    while choice>=1:
        if choice==1:
            roll_1=random.randint(1,6)
            thisset.append(roll_1)
            choice=choice-1
        if choice==2:
            roll_2=random.randint(1,6)
            thisset.append(roll_2)
            choice=choice-1
        if choice==3:
            roll_3=random.randint(1,6)
            thisset.append(roll_3)
            choice=choice-1
        if choice==4:
            roll_4=random.randint(1,6)
            thisset.append(roll_4)
            choice=choice-1
        if choice==5:
            roll_5=random.randint(1,6)
            thisset.append(roll_5)
            choice=choice-1
    return thisset
print(all_dice(choice))
```

The sample output that I got was:-

```
[3, 1, 6, 5, 2]
```

The `set` cannot have duplicates so I have used `list`.